# VBA ListView column autosize after UserForm .Hide then .Show

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, userform, common-controls

I have a UserForm that uses a `ListView` control (from Microsoft Common Controls).

To autosize the columns of this `ListView` I use the following WinAPI call within the UserForm, which works fine and correctly sets the size of the column:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Const LVM_FIRST = &H1000
Private Const LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH = (LVM_FIRST + 30)
Private Const LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER = -2

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Autosizes the first column of the ListView
    SendMessage ListView.hWnd, LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH, 0, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER
End Sub
```

However, if I hide and then re-show the UserForm (e.g. using `Me.Hide` and `Me.Show` in a `CommandButton` event) this WinAPI call goes wrong and sets the column width to ~16,000 pixels.

I assume the error is because the `hWnd` of the `ListView` and/or UserForm itself is changed after the hide and show.

Is anyone aware of a fix for this issue?

Comment: Did you get any error code after the call? I am not familiar with VBA but I cannot repro it on a c++ project with listview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm attempting to create a minimal example within Excel but I'm currently failing. I'll continue to try and replicate the issue.